# passing additional parameters to two function

Tags: r

I want to pass parameters to two functions. I try the `...`, but seems the `...` pass all the parameters to the first function. My trial code is below, but with errors.

```
f_add <- function(a = 1, b = 1){
  return(a+b)
}
f_minus <- function(c = 1, d = 2){
  return(c - d)
}
f_1 <- function(...){
  f_add(...) + f_minus(...)
}
```

Errors:

```
f_1(a = 1, b =2 , c = 3, d = 4)
## Error in f_add(...) : unused arguments (c = 3, d = 4)
## Called from: f_add(...)
## Browse[1]> Q
```

So here I ask for any easy way to design the functions.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to pass the parameters from the top function to the inner two functions, but i don't want specify the parameters one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allow the function `f_add` and `f_minus` to take unnamed arguments, and ignore them:

```
f_add <- function(a = 1, b = 1, ...){
  return(a+b)
}
f_minus <- function(c = 1, d = 2, ...){
  return(c - d)
}
f_1 <- function(...){
  f_add(...) + f_minus(...)
}
```

This admits your desired computation:

```
f_1(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
## [1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f_add <- function(a = 1, b = 1){
  return(a+b)
}
f_minus <- function(c = 1, d = 2){
  return(c - d)
}
f_1 <- function(a,b,c,d){
  f_add(a,b) + f_minus(c,d)
}

f_1(a=1,b=100,c=2000,d=5)
2096
```